I keep having to run npx tailwindcss -i ./src/input.css -o ./public/output.css to see the expected output of my code
In my project, I will have a div that is styled:
<div class="pt-14 px-30">
<p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
</div>

and if i change it to <div class="pt-10 px-20": both properties will be ignored.
After looking on Stack Overflow, I ran the command npx tailwindcss -i ./src/input.css -o ./public/output.css and the expected output would show, but I would have to run this command every time I changed my CSS to see the correct output. Is there a way I can get around this and see the output after saving the file?
